# Password protecting ATOM feeds

Tags: asp.net, authorization, atom-feed

The Twitter ATOM feed requires your login and password (obviously), which is nicely supported by IE7 (apparently IE7 can't handle RSS feeds with login/pw). IE displays a simple login prompt when you register the feed.

How do I implement something similar in ASP.NET without access to the server or IIS?

Answer (score 1):

You could send a header manually with some basic ASP to request generic http authentication.

( Copied from: http://psacake.com/web/fl.asp )

You could also define authentication settings in your web.config if you're using asp.net

<!-- Web.config file -->
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="basic" />
</system.web>

Comment: Wouldn't that solution (<authentication mode="basic" /> in web.config) require that I have permission to create users on the server? The solution is going to be hosted somewhere, where I probably can't create Windows accounts on the server.